# Using cask and then brew install

Tags: homebrew

I am trying to install gulp - which seems to require first cask:

```
17:14:34/mozaik-demo $brew install gulp
Error: No available formula for gulp
Searching formulae...
Searching taps...
Caskroom/cask/gulp
```

Let us install the cask:

```
17:14:41/mozaik-demo $brew cask install gulp
==> Downloading https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-app/releases/download/0.1.0/gulp.app.zip
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Symlinking App 'gulp.app' to '/Users/steve/Applications/gulp.app'
  gulp staged at '/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/gulp/0.1.0' (830 files, 75M)
```

But then what is the correct next step? Here is my attempt:

```
17:15:03/mozaik-demo $brew install gulp
Error: No available formula for gulp
Searching formulae...
Searching taps...
Caskroom/cask/gulp
17:15:09/mozaik-demo $which gulp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do `brew install gulp` after `brew cask install gulp`. Once `brew cask install gulp` end, you have your app installed on `/Users/steve/Applications/gulp.app`, you don't need any extra steps.

Comment: do I need to add /Users/steve/Applications to my path then?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Last line of the OP:  " $which gulp".  None in the path.  I will in any case add it and see what happens

Comment: I do not know how to use gulp.app.  21:55:35/mozaik-demo $gulp publish
bash: gulp: command not found

Comment: I am going to look up cask install, seems to be stuff going on that I need to better understand.

Comment: Gulp is a graphical app, you have to go to `/Users/steve/Applications` and double click on `gulp` to open.

Comment: I am following directions that say "gulp publish"  so then how to do that? There is a gulpfile.js in the given directory. This is probably a node.js thing. I know almost zero about node

Comment: What you install from `brew cask` is this: https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-app Don't seems that allow `gulp publish`.

Comment: You are headed the right direction on this thanks.